# C++ 23 Does std::print or std::println flush the output stream?

Tags: c++, stl, fmt, c++23

Prior to C++ 23, when using `std::cout` to send output to `stdout`, there is a distinction between the following two ways of adding a new line at the end of the printed string:

- `std::cout << "Hello World\n"`;
- `std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;`

The second of these is often preferable as it causes the output stream to flush, rather than requiring a call to `std::cout.flush()`.

With C++ 23 there are now two new functions for printing, along with a new component to the standard library. We have `std::print` and `std::println`.

Do either of these functions make a distinction when it comes to flushing the output stream?

Or, is it the case that flushing the output stream is no longer a concept which is relevant in these new implementations?

Documentation from `cppreference` does not mention flushing:

- [cppreference: print](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print)
- [cppreference: println](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/println)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the standard doesn't specify explicitly; however, the function call is the equivalent of `vprint_nonunicode` or `vprint_unicode` with `stdout` as it's first parameter. These in turn have the effect of writing `vformat` to the stream. Since `vformat` would not flush, it stands to reason that `vprint_(non)unicode` would not, and thus `print` would not.

See [`print.fun`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/print.fun)

Note: not in the html version, but the updated .tex file for the standard does state that there is a flush prior to the print. https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/main/source/iostreams.tex

> If the native Unicode API is used, the function flushes \tcode{os} before writing \tcode{out}

Answer (score 2):

The stream is not explicitly flushed, except if the ordinary literal encoding is UTF-8 and the stream is connected to a Unicode-aware terminal (as determined in an implementation-defined matter). This is a special case where the new `<print>` additions guarantee correct encoding for the terminal (which the old C++ IO does not guarantee). See [P2093](https://wg21.link/p2093#unicode).

But in that case the stream is only flushed *before* writing the output and only to avoid potential synchronization issues with the underlying stream. See [P2539](https://wg21.link/p2539).

Of course the underlying stream is usually line-buffered if connected to an interactive terminal, so that writing `'\n'` to it implies a flush. But that is implementation-defined. It seems that with the Windows CRT there is even a flush after every library call if connected to a character device, according to P2539 above.

So it behaves like `printf` or the single `<<` in the old C++ IO API in that regard. If a flush is required outside of the implementation-defined buffering behavior mentioned above, then it must be done manually as before, using `std::flush` or `std::fflush`.

Maybe relevant is that `std::print`/`std::println` without explicit stream/`FILE*` argument will print to `stdout`, not `std::cout`, so if `sync_with_stdio` was set to `false`, only `std::fflush(stdout)` should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not specify this.

I have looked at Microsoft STL sources of [print](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/853d9565df8f9d6e72a9a3bc9a60fdeff2861a32/stl/inc/print) and MS `print` flushes streams if they output to an Unicode console. It seems they want to avoid undesired splitting bytes of multibyte characters when several streams output to a console.